# AWS SDK C++: putting an object in S3 with server side encryption

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

It's very easy to select server side encryption in S3 when putting an object with the AWS SDK PHP:

```
$result = $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $key,
    'SourceFile' => $source_file,
    'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256'
));
```

Putting an object in S3 with the AWS SDK C++ looks similar to:

```
Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest object_request;
object_request.WithBucket(bucket_name).WithKey(key_name);
auto input_data = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::FStream>(key_name.c_str(), dir_name.c_str(), std::ios_base::in);
object_request.SetBody(input_data);
auto put_object_outcome = s3_client.PutObject(object_request);
```

But, how can you select server side encryption with the AWS SDK C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution:

```
object_request.WithServerSideEncryption(Aws::S3::Model::ServerSideEncryption::AES256);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're using v1 of the sdk, so you can achieve this using the [`WithServerSideEncryptionMethod`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_Model_PutObjectRequest_WithServerSideEncryptionMethod.htm)

```
object_request.WithServerSideEncryptionMethod(ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256);
```